# Storing information from php script

Tags: javascript, php

I m working on an html page that contains a form allowing users to enter their informations and upload files. all informations will be inserted in Mysql database.

in Javascript, im using XMLHttpRequest to send the files to the server and "upload.php" to rename (to avoid dupplicated names) and move them in the upload directory.
For better user experience, this will be done before submitting the whole form.

My question is : How can i store the new filenames (defined in upload.php)to use them in the form submission "submit.php"?
the reason for this is that in "submit.php", i insert first the user informations in "user" table and then select the "user_id" (auto increment) that will be inserted with filenames in the "files" table.

Could php sessions be an approach to do this ? is there another way? Thanks for your help

html:

```
<form action="submit.php" method="post" id="submitform">
<div>
<--!user info part1-->
</div>
<div id="filesContainer" class="eltContainer">
    <input type="file" id="filesList" multiple>
</div>
<div>
<--!user info part2-->
</div>
```

javascript:

```
var fd = new FormData()
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
for (var i=0,nb = fichiers.length; i<nb; i++) {
    var fichier = fichiers[i]
    fd.append(fichier.name,fichier)
}
xhr.open('POST', 'upload.php', true)
```

upload.php :

```
<?php 
foreach($_FILES as $file){
    $filename = date('Y') . date('m') . date('d') . date('H') . date('i') . basename($_FILES[$file]['name']);
    move_uploaded_file( $file['tmp_name'],"../upload_dir/" .$filename);  
    }
exit;
```

Comment: simple: start a db transaction, insert a skeleton record (bare minimum necessary to create the record), get its insert ID, use that ID to build your filename, then update the record/commit the transaction once you've completed the file manipulations.

Comment: when inserting filename in the DB, i dont need the file insert id, but the user insert id(as foreign key). The problem is when i do file manipulation/insertion i havn't reached yet the user insertion wich comes after submitting the whole form.. i also want to minimize the db transactions. Thanks anyway

Comment: same thing holds. create a placeholder user record so you can get a userID, which you can then attach to the placeholder file record, blah blah blah. all you'd need afterwards is a janitor script to kill any abandoned skeletons so you don't fill the db with partials.

Comment: in this case, i'll need the file name or ID to attach the userID to the placeholder. The question remains, how can i store the file infos up to this point?

Comment: so stuff the file info into another table. store the IDs of those records in the session. once the user is full registered, you can go into this other table and copy/move the data to the "permanent" tables, and do any necessary renaming/processing them. if the user doesn't complete registration, you just nuke any stale entries from those 'temp' tables, and delete any files the records are pointing at.

Comment: @BenS. Beware, your code allows users to upload files with somewhat arbitrary names.  If I want to upload `something-evil.exe`, I can, and you'll just prepend the date on it.  This isn't good.  Furthermore, it's possible to move up in the file system by sending in `../` in the filename.  This is very dangerous.  Use UUID to generate a filename, or name files based on their IDs in your database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would consider using something like [md5](http://php.net/manual/pl/function.md5.php) for unique filenames.

Nevertheless you can push filenames into some array, and than return those filenames, as a result of post request, and put them back into some input field.

To retrieve the response simply add this lines to your code below `open`

```
xhr.onreadystatechange = function {
// If the request completed and status is OK
  if (req.readyState == 4 && req.status == 200) {
    // keep in mind that fileNames here are JSON string
    // as you should call json_encode($arrayOfFilenames)
    // in your php script (upload.php)
    var fileNames = xhr.responseText; 
  }
}
```

If you'd like consider using a simple library for AJAX requests, like [axios](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios). It's promise based HTTP client for the browser, really simple to use and saves you some time and effort cause you don't have to memorize all this stuff you and I have just written.

This is one approach, but I think you can use `$_SESSION` as well, and it's perfectly valid. My guess is you don't have logged in user at this point, so my idea is as follows:

- put filenames into the `$_SESSION`
- use db transactions - as @Marc B suggested - to connect files with
  user
- if there were no errors just remove filenames from $_SESSION, if there was some, just redirect the user back to the form (possibly with some info what went wrong), and **this way he doesn't have to reupload files**, cause you have filenames still in `$_SESSION`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But "upload.php" is called in the XMLHttpRequest API in javascript, how can i then get the result of post request?

Comment: I have modified my answer including this information.

Comment: "xhr.responseText" is exactly what i needed. I'll continue digging also in php sessions and see which one to use. Thanks for your help.